# Confusion solving $\frac{u_x}{x}+\frac{u_y}{y}+\frac{u_z}{z}=\frac{u}{1-u}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How do I solve this PDE:

$$\frac{u_x}{x}+\frac{u_y}{y}+\frac{u_z}{z}=\frac{u}{1-u} \hspace{2cm} u(\sqrt{y^2+z^2},y,z)=g(y)$$

I think we must write:

$$\frac{dx}{1/x}=\frac{dy}{1/y}=\frac{dz}{1/z}=\frac{du}{u/(u-1)}$$

Which yields:

$$x \;dx = y\; dy \\ x \;dx = z \;dz \\ x \;dx = \frac{u-1}{u} \;du $$

I think integrating them, I'd get:

$$\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{y^2}{2}+c1$$

$$\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{z^2}{2}+c2$$

$$\frac{x^2}{2}=u-\log(u)+c3$$

I am a bit lost now: What do I do?

Comment: What makes you think that we can get an explicit solution to this nonlinear partial differential equation? Is this even a well posed problem? What's the domain? Do you have any boundary conditions? This is some sort of nonlinear advection equation of the form $a(\mathbf{x}) \cdot \nabla u = f(u)$.

Comment: @PierreCarre Wait, I may have confused something. It seems there is an initial condition which is $u(\sqrt{y^2+z^2},y,z)=g(y)$.

Comment: It looks like you want the method of characteristic to solve for u as a function of x,y,z https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics

Comment: What is “g(y)” there is no g in the problem as stated?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas I think it's any continuous function?

Comment: Anyways after applying the method of characteristics there is some weird lambert W function stuff going on with the “u” part of the system. So even that isn’t smooth sailing

Comment: @frogeyedpeas. You are right, the LambertW function is necessary if one want the explicit solution. But it is not necessary to find the solution on the form of an implicit equation.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{u_x}{x}+\frac{u_y}{y}+\frac{u_z}{z}=\frac{u}{1-u} \tag 1$$
You correctly wrote the Charpit-Lagrange ODEs :

$$\frac{dx}{1/x}=\frac{dy}{1/y}=\frac{dz}{1/z}=\frac{du}{u/(u-1)}$$

A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{1/x}=\frac{dy}{1/y}$ :
$$x^2-y^2=C_1$$

A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{1/x}=\frac{dz}{1/z}$ :
$$x^2-z^2=C_2$$

A third characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{1/x}=\frac{du}{u/(u-1)}$ :
$$ue^{-u}e^{-x^2/2}=C_3$$

The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation is $\Psi(C_1\:,\:C_2\:,\:C_3)=0$ with arbitrary function $\Psi$ of three arguments. Or equivalently $C_3=\Phi(C_1\:,\:C_2)$ :
$$ue^{-u}e^{-x^2/2}=\Phi\left( (x^2-y^2)\:,\:(x^2-z^2)\right)$$
The function of two arguments $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function until the boundary condition be taken into account.
$$\boxed{ue^{-u}=e^{x^2/2}\:\Phi\left( (x^2-y^2)\:,\:(x^2-z^2)\right)} \tag 2$$
$u(x,y,z)$ can be expressed on explicit form thanks to a special function as this will be shown latter. We don't need it to continue.

CONDITION : $u(\sqrt{y^2+z^2},y,z)=g(y)$

In order to avoid missunderstanding the calculus will be shown in full details.

$u(\sqrt{y^2+z^2},y,z)=g(y)$ has to be satisfied any $y,z$ that is whatever the symbols are. Thus this is equivalent to
$$u(\sqrt{\lambda^2+\mu^2},\lambda,\mu)=g(\lambda)\quad\text{ any }\lambda,\mu.$$
We put it into Eq.$(2)$ :
$$g(\lambda)e^{-g(\lambda)}=e^{\frac{\lambda^2+\mu^2}{2}}\:\Phi\left( ((\lambda^2+\mu^2)-\lambda^2)\:,\:((\lambda^2+\mu^2)-\mu^2)\right)$$

$$g(\lambda)e^{-g(\lambda)}=e^{\frac{\lambda^2+\mu^2}{2}}\:\Phi\left( \mu^2\:,\:\lambda^2\right)$$

$$g(\lambda)e^{-g(\lambda)}e^{-\lambda^2/2}=e^{\mu^2/2}\:\Phi\left( \mu^2\:,\:\lambda^2\right)$$
The term on the left isn't function of $\mu$. Thus the term on the right isn't function of $\mu$ which implies
$$\Phi\left( \mu^2\:,\:\lambda^2\right)=e^{-\mu^2/2}F(\lambda)$$
with $F$ arbitrary function of $\lambda$.
$$g(\lambda)e^{-g(\lambda)}e^{-\lambda^2/2}=F\left(\lambda\right)$$
$$\Phi\left( \mu^2\:,\:\lambda^2\right)=e^{-\mu^2/2}g(\lambda) e^{-g(\lambda)}e^{-\lambda^2/2}$$

$$\Phi\left( \mu^2\:,\:\lambda^2\right)=e^{-(\lambda^2+\mu^2)/2}g(\lambda) e^{-g(\lambda)}$$
Now the function $\Phi$ is determined. We will put it into the general solution Eq.$(2)$ where $\mu^2=(x^2-y^2)$ and $\lambda^2=(x^2-z^2)$ :
$$\Phi\left( (x^2-y^2)\:,\:(x^2-z^2)\right)=e^{-(2x^2-y^2-z^2)/2}g\left(\sqrt{x^2-z^2}\right) e^{-g\left(\sqrt{x^2-z^2}\right)}$$

$$ue^{-u}=e^{x^2/2}\:e^{-(2x^2-y^2-z^2)/2}g\left(\sqrt{x^2-z^2}\right) e^{-g\left(\sqrt{x^2-z^2}\right)}$$

$$\boxed{ue^{-u}=e^{(-x^2+y^2+z^2)/2}g\left(\sqrt{x^2-z^2}\right) e^{-g\left(\sqrt{x^2-z^2}\right)}} \tag 3$$
This is the solution on implicit form, which satisfies the condition.

On explicit form :
$$u(x,y,z)=-W\left(-e^{(-x^2+y^2+z^2)/2}g\left(\sqrt{x^2-z^2}\right) e^{-g\left(\sqrt{x^2-z^2}\right)} \right)$$
$W$ is the LambertW function. Note that the function $W(X)$ is multivalued. The real values are denoted $W_0(X)$ and $W_{-1}(X)$. See : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

Comment: Shouldn't the first characteristic be $\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}=C_1$? Do you multiply them by $2$ so they become easier to deal with?

Comment: $$\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}=c_1$$ $$C_1=2c_1$$ $$x^2-y^2=C_1$$ This is equivalent since $c_1$ or $C_1$ are arbitrary. .